# TSQL Insert additional rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What is the most efficient way to identify and insert rows for the following problem?

Here's my sample data

```
vId StartDate   EndDate     Distance
------------------------------------    
256 2015-03-04  2015-03-05  365
271 2015-03-04  2015-03-04  86
315 2015-03-05  2015-03-06  254
256 2015-03-07  2015-03-09  150
458 2015-03-10  2015-03-12  141
458 2015-03-15  2015-03-17  85
315 2015-03-15  2015-03-16  76
```

I want to add additional rows for each `vId` where the `StartDate <> EndDate` like follows, so instead of just

```
315 2015-03-05  2015-03-06  254
256 2015-03-07  2015-03-09  150
```

I want to show the following

```
315 2015-03-05  2015-03-06  254
315 2015-03-06  2015-03-06  0

256 2015-03-07  2015-03-09  150
256 2015-03-08  2015-03-09  0
256 2015-03-09  2015-03-09  0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple insert:

```
Insert Into Table(vId, StartDate, EndDate, Distance)
Select vId, DateAdd(dd, 1, StartDate), EndDate, 0
From TableName
Where StartDate <> EndDate
```

If you want just select but not insert then:

```
Select vId, StartDate, EndDate, Distance
From TableName

Union All

Select vId, DateAdd(dd, 1, StartDate), EndDate, 0
From TableName
Where StartDate <> EndDate
```

**EDIT**

This assumes that there are maximum 100 day difference. If you have longer intervals you can add more cross joins to increase possible values:

```
declare @t table(vId int, StartDate date, EndDate date, Distance int)

insert into @t values
(315, '2015-03-05',  '2015-03-06',  254),
(256, '2015-03-07',  '2015-03-09',  150)


;with cte as(select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
             from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1(n)
             cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t2(n)
            )

select * from @t
union all
select t1.vId, ca.StartDate, t1.EndDate, 0 
from @t t1
cross apply(select dateadd(dd, c.rn, StartDate) as StartDate 
            from cte c 
            where dateadd(dd, c.rn, t1.StartDate) <= t1.EndDate) as ca
where t1.StartDate <> t1.EndDate
order by vId, StartDate
```

See fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4641

Comment: That works fine it seems when the difference between StartDate and EndDate is only 1 day.  I have rows where the difference is more than one day.

Comment: I didn't understand the question if it was question

Comment: I have updated the question to explain this clearly. The difference for the following is 2 days  `256 2015-03-07  2015-03-09  150`.  So I need two additional rows.